# No error message is shown when trying to favorite a deleted question

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions, bookmarks, popups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Deleted Questions in Favorites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97109/deleted-questions-in-favorites)

Minor issue. If you try to favourite a deleted question (hey, I was curious), the star lights up and the count increments, but there's no popup error like you get if you try to vote:

> This post has been deleted; deleted posts can't be voted on. (click on this box to dismiss)

The vote doesn't actually go through, but the counter and star status isn't reset until the page is reloaded.

[Here's a random deleted question to test with](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55131)

Comment: You might want to pick a random deleted question on StackOverflow, as I'm still 700 away from being able to view that question on Meta.

Comment: @Chacha: Sorry, I don't have 10k on SO. Feel free to edit in a link from there if you'd like.

Comment: I'm now curious what happens if you favorited the question post deletion, does it remove the mark? I *think* I managed to do that, once. But I obviously can't see it in my favorites section. I've also gone and marked an already deleted question (I had the page cache'd) as a favorite. Can't really confirm if it's still favorited, though!

Comment: The favourite votes are retained, since a question can be undeleted. The questions are simply filtered out in the favourites list. The question I linked to above has a favourite count of 1, so I'm assuming the same bug exists if you try to unfavourite a deleted question as well. @Grace