# Deleted Questions in Favorites

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, bookmarks, 10k-tools

This is two closely related things: a possible *bug* with the favorites implementation, and *suggestions* for changes to the favorites feature.

---

When trying to remove [this](https://superuser.com/questions/232273/how-do-i-stop-mac-os-x-snow-leopard-from-losing-the-keyboard-shortcuts-i-create-i) deleted question from my favorites by clicking the star, I get the following:

[image]

The message is ridiculous, and *removing* from favorites should still work. It's not a serious issue, since deleted questions don't appear in the favorites list, but it's still very odd behavior (especially the message that is displayed). It might also clog the SQL tubes.

---

Here's the suggestion:

In light of flagging and possibly undeleting questions, *adding* to favorites would also make (at least some) sense; so there's no reason to restrict the favorites link for deleted questions — it can only be done by 10k+ rep users anyway, and one could assume they know what they're doing (some of the time).

It would also probably make sense for one's own favorite deleted questions to be visible for 10k+ users, so it's clear what happened to them (instead of simply disappearing), and allowing users to explicitly remove them from the favorites list, flag them, or starting the undelete process — it's probably the interesting questions that end up being favorites, so if they get removed, there's an above average chance that something went wrong. Again, it only applies to 10k+ rep users that have been around for a while.

Comment: well adding to favourites is (internally) another vote, that's why you get the message

Answer (score 7, accepted):

10k+ users can now see, add and remove deleted questions in their favorites list.

They can also add and remove a favorite question from the Questions/Show page.

Comment: Wow! Nice, this is an amazing feature. Thanks!

Comment: So you can be awarded a [badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/33/favorite-question) posthumously?

Comment: @DoubleAA no, only undeleted questions are eligible for that badge.

Comment: @JarrodDixon I suppose [this badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/17/necromancer) might have been more appropriate anyway :)