# Is there a guarantee that marked questions as favorites will not be deleted and can I reread them in the future?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, up-votes, bookmarks

Is there a period after which the question can not be deleted? Similarly for upvoted questions and answers.
Maybe for deleted questions assign a unique hash code. Thus we can reread in the future (usually for the author and for those who marked as a favorite (and/or upvoted)).

Comment: The only way to save those things for sure is external place. Keep a text file with the direct links to the questions then when you'll have 10K rep you will be able to see them all, deleted or not deleted.

Comment: Related; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted

Comment: Related: [Notification when a favorite was closed or deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77092)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, questions can be deleted at any time, there is no period of time whereby a question is locked.

Questions can be deleted for a number of reasons:

- The poster no longer wishes the question to remain
- The scope of the website changes somewhat and what was considered a suitable question is no longer appropriate
- The question could be identified as being plagirised from elsewhere so the original owner requests it be removed...

Unfortunately there is no way to ensure they question is always available I'm afraid. Older ones are less likely to be deleted than newer ones, particularly if they have been upvoted a fair number of times so that may give you a hint as to the future of those questions, but anything can happen in the future.

Comment: Note that for good questions that also have good answer, the first point isn't necessarily a good reason to delete. We can disassociate a post from the owner (they have a right to that under the CC license), but if the question is useful, we may deny the request to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

No, marking anything as a favourite does not prevent deletion. And if you don't have sufficient rep (>10k) you will not be able to see the question once it has been deleted.

Comment: Would it still appear in your favourites if it's deleted though?

Comment: @Jack only if you have over 10K rep, then it appears red. :)

Comment: To add to Shadow Wizard's comment, that feature is described here: [Deleted Questions in Favorites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97110)

Answer (score 2):

No there's no guarantee, if a question is closed it might get deleted at any time.

If you feel that a closed question should not be deleted, then work towards getting it re-opened. If you don't see any way of getting it re-opened and want to somehow preserve it, then do so off site.